# Order a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table like this

```
title                season     episode     date_modified 
================================================================
a series             1          1           2021-03-15 10:41:42
a series             1          2           2021-03-16 10:41:42
b series             1          1           2021-03-15 10:41:42
b series             1          2           2021-03-14 10:41:42
c series             1          1           2021-03-15 10:41:42
c series             1          2           2021-03-18 10:41:42
```

now I want to order this table by `title` then `episode` but on top of that, I want to order it by `date_modified` but only with the latest data from the group of title, so that the latest series` episode is at the top. I don't know how to describe it with words, but it should be something like this

```
title                season     episode     date_modified 
================================================================
c series             1          1           2021-03-15 10:41:42
c series             1          2           2021-03-18 10:41:42  <-- latest update
a series             1          1           2021-03-15 10:41:42
a series             1          2           2021-03-16 10:41:42  <-- 2nd latest update
b series             1          1           2021-03-15 10:41:42
b series             1          2           2021-03-14 10:41:42
```

I tried `ORDER BY title asc, episode asc, date_modified DESC` but I know that's not the right answer. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Use subquery for to extract latest update per title. Or window function if your server version allows.

Comment: @tadman ? Eh? No it doesn't.

Comment: The sorting order in the `b series` appears to be backwards.  Is that intentional, or do you want to correct your expected output?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no it is correct because order by episode asc

Comment: Please share the full and exact query you are using. Also why do you expect that the list is ordered by title descending, while your query contains `ORDER BY title asc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL 8+

```sql
SELECT *
FROM source_table
ORDER BY MAX(date_modified) OVER (PARTITION BY title) DESC, title, episode;
```

MySQL 5.x

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM source_table t1
JOIN ( SELECT title, MAX(date_modified) date_modified
       FROM source_table t2 
       GROUP BY title ) t3 USING (title)
ORDER BY t3.date_modified DESC, t1.title, t1.episode
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&rdbms2=mysql_5.7&fiddle=df308ca8e8319dc4ff186fa8928e55a1) (thanks to **Tim Biegeleisen** for source data).

Comment: I use MySQL 5.x one but it only shows one row per title

Comment: @Imo Maybe you have taken old version? I had edited the query... see demo fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

We can try sorting with the help of `MAX()` used as an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT title, season, episode, date_modified
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY MAX(date_modified) OVER (PARTITION BY title) DESC, episode, date_modified;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: I wonder why this isn't work then I realized that i'm using mysql 5.x

Comment: ...consider upgrading to MySQL 8+ and save some source code writing.